# Ajax form submit error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the code below to send an email via ajax. The problem is that even if the email is not sent e.g i localhost or when there is no internet connection, the success command will still be returned by the script. Kindly advise me on what modifications I should make to the code for it to detect whenever an error is encountered.

```
$('#send_button').click(function(e) {
     $("#sending").removeClass("hidden_div");//just to know that we have some data

     alerts = '';
     if($("input[name=names]").val() == ''){
        alerts += "1";
        $("#error_name").removeClass("hidden_div");
     }

     if(alerts != ''){
        $("#sending").addClass("hidden_div");
     } else {
         $.ajax({
                url:'index.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:$("#form").serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){ 
                    show_ok();
                },
                error: function(){
                    $("#msg_not_sent").removeClass("hidden_div");
                    $( "#msg_not_sent" ).empty().append( "An error has occurred. Kindly try again." );
                  }
        });     }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I assume index.php exists, so the Ajax post will succeed. It will make a POST with the form data to index.php. It doesn't matter that the index.php won't succeed in sending the email since it is not the asynchronous Ajax call concern anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this happens if the code you are calling doesn't error in the way jQuery expects, or you aren't using a matching return data type you can get this. There's a way around it though.

```
complete: function (data) {
    if (data.status == "200") {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` should contain a `success` property.

Since your call *will* most likely will succeed, you need to also take into account the result of the action.

PHP:

```
$success = false;
if(somethingOk){
    $success = true;
}
echo json_encode(array(
    'success' => $success
));
```

JS:

```
dataType: 'json',        // make sure you get a json
success: function(data){ 
    if (data.success){
        show_ok();
    } else {
        alert("error");
    }
},
```